# Access AJAX data via PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I've been banging my head for 3 days trying to figure out how to access this AJAX JSON object via PHP. Here is the function that I have

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "BPHCalcEnter.php",
              data: {'lastName': "Hello"},
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                    setTimeout(function (){
                    $(".container").html(data)
                    }, 1000);
               }
});
```

And here's the PHP code from BPHCalcEnter.php

```
  $myVar = $_POST['lastName'];
  json_decode($data);
  echo "var myval = foo($myVar);";
```

It shows var myVar = foo(); as if the variable is receiving nothing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: You are returning JavaScript not JSON.

Comment: Start with something like `var_dump($_POST);` in the PHP file to see what you receive. Then work from there.

Comment: data: {'lastName': "Hello"} this is a javascript object and  data: {"lastName": "Hello"} here it is a json object

Comment: The only difference in this example between a JS object and JSON are the single quotes around lastName?

Answer (score 0):

remove from ajax

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
```

You are not passing json from php.you are just echoing string

Comment: Ok this seemed to work. It now shows var myVar = foo(Hello); But now,  it looks like my containers are being repeated I suspect it's due to this 
    setTimeout(function (){
                    $(".container").html(data)
                    }, 1000);  Is there a better way of doing this? It doesn't seem to work with nothing in success either

Comment: try  $(".container").html('') .html(data)},

Comment: Still same. You can view the problem at http://www.gearedwebdesigns.com/BPHCalcEnter.php just above the html table. It looks fine (but without the ajax variable) for about a second then it looks like it refreshes and the ajax variable is displayed above the html table but it's like my entire code is repeated 3 times.

Comment: Any other ideas? I don't quite understand. Is there another way with Ajax? I have seen the alert used instead of settimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

Echo is used to display output, you can use double quote and variable it will print the value but same doesn't work for function call.

echo "var myval = ".foo($myVar);

Comment: This gives me an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function foo() in /home2/gearedwe/public_html/BPHCalcEnter.php on line 55

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove the simple quote into your data propriety for the key on the Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "BPHCalcEnter.php",
          data: {lastName: "Hello"}, //remove simple quote on the key
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function (){
                $(".container").html(data)
                }, 1000);
           }
```

});

Comment: This didn't seem to affect anything.